# How do I burn the Ubuntu ISO to a CD?

Tags: system-installation

How do I burn the latest 12.10 790 MB ISO to a CD?

My burning software says insert a disk but 700 MB CD's are too small. I tried a DVD and that didn't work either.

Comment: There are also CDs with ~800mb capacity

Comment: this is about the newer images being too big for cd - not the old barely fitting.

Comment: Alternatively, use the [minimal image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

Comment: It was decided at the Ubuntu 12.04 UDS that the ISO image would be allowed to exceed the space of a CD. However, it wasn't until 12.10 that the image actually began requiring a DVD.

Answer (score 33):

This was a decision made some time ago by Canonical, the corporate backers for **Ubuntu**.

See: [OMG! Ubuntu > It’s Official: The Ubuntu LiveCD is Dead](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/its-official-the-ubuntu-livecd-is-dead)

> The news came from Canonical’s Kate Stewart on the Ubuntu Mailing list, who wrote:
>
> > *There  is no longer a traditional CD sized image, DVD or alternate image, but >> rather a single 800MB Ubuntu image that can be used from USB or DVD.*

---

I stopped burning a CD (or DVD) for ISO files about 2 years ago.

A cheap 2GB Flash USB drive is **3-4 times faster** for installs, and can be repeatedly reused (for later releases).

Comment: DVDs still work...

Comment: *Yes, but many Notebooks no longer have a optical-media drive, and USB is just plain **faster**.*

Answer (score 15):

The ubuntu page mentions that 12.10 can no longer be written on a CD because of its size.

Also, there's no such thing as a "CD iso image", it's just an iso image, so just write it on a DVD and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 10):

There is also a "mini.iso" network install that will burn to CD and will download the needed packages from the internet.

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/12.10/

This will not give you a live CD but will give you a way to install Ubuntu with a CD and your internet.

Answer (score 7):

There were many talks about the final size for Ubuntu 12.10. The decision was made that the CD size was not capable of handling the amount of packages and ideas that the developers wanted to put in 12.10, like for example Python3 and all other packages related to it. Additionally, since both DVD and USB are more used than common CD (Not all parts of the world, but most of them), the final decision was then made to start building against the DVD and USB sizes, starting with a size around 800MB, which eventually ended around 700MB but still, a couple of megabytes above the biggest size for a common CD disc (Assuming you are using a 650 or 700 size one).

So for 12.10, you can either use a DVD disc or USB (Pen drive, Flash drive...). This gives you 2 benefits:

1. Faster loading than CD (Since reading a DVD or USB is much faster than a CD)
2. Faster installation than CD (Same reason as point 1)

Note that this only affects the Desktop version, since the Server version still supports a CD size. Also note that this talk was also mentioned for 12.04 but in that case, they waited for 12.10 instead of applying the size change in 12.04.

In my personal opinion, with the increase in size of many programs, for example games (That even go out to sizes of bluray), and large download installer (Like in steam), or OS updates like the Windows 7 SP1, sizes bigger than 1 GB are more common. So it was just a matter of time before this really needed decision was made, which should help in promote more options for end users (Like me trying to see aptitude implemente again ^^). Hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 7):

> Ubuntu 12.10 will increase the maximum size of its disc image from
>   700MB to 800MB, thereby making it too big to fit onto traditional CD-R
>   media.
>
> The news came from Canonical’s Kate Stewart on the [Ubuntu Mailing](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2012-September/000161.html)
>   list, who wrote:
>
> > "There  is no longer a traditional CD sized image, DVD or alternate
> >     image, but rather a single 800MB Ubuntu image that can be used from
> >     USB or DVD."
>
> Ubuntu Server remains unaffected by the switch.

Source: [OMGUbuntu.com](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/its-official-the-ubuntu-livecd-is-dead)

Answer (score 4):

## You can't

live cd option is no longer available for ubuntu, you should use live dvd or usb disk :)

Comment: Where is the DVD ISO for 12.10 ?

Answer (score 4):

I would start by taking out the additional language files such as French, Spanish, ... This usually reduces the size by 100 or so MB. The files can be found in the source root of the disc.

Answer (score 3):

If you know someone who knows how to repackage a boot image and modify the config files it can be done, im sick of people who just reply "you cant", it can be done, but like i said, you need someone who knows how to modify the 790mb image (perhaps leaving out a few measly pkgs or drivers you dont need). I have done this in the past...

Oh and there aren't just 2 options, Linux can be installed many ways not just USB and DVDs exist in the real world ya know... the MiniCD (34mb) or even better, if you have a machine already set up with PXE, or have a windows machine handy, you can set it up with  TFTPD and set up a pxe boot and get the ubuntu distros for it, i have tried this and it does work.. just google around you'll find lots of different ways to do this. I am currently working on shrinking the build to 700mb because i have 7 machines that need installs and none of them have DVD drives (all cd) and whats worse they are servers and have no way of using my IDE DVDROM cause its SCSI-LVD.. so.. if i ever get this done or find someone else who can do it for me i'll get back to ya, good luck -- hope that helps... (maybe?)

PS: My suggestion for you: Install Ubuntu 12.10 SERVER (comes with no gui) and then install the GUI separately if you know even a little linux this should be sufficient... or heres a link on how to do it if you dont know how..should get you started and hopefully done and on to better things...

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-gui-in-ubuntu-server.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have two options for the 12.10 standard-image:

1. USB flashdrive
2. DVD

To create a USB flashdrive, you can follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick). To create a proper DVD follow [the instructions here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto).

Regards.

Comment: Where is the DVD ISO for 12.10 ? I have downloaded 12.04 DVD iso. It looks like the 12.10 iso is only for 800Meg CD's

Comment: There isn't an iso explicitly labeled as DVD. As you stated, 800 MB don't fit on a CD. So the only way to get it onto a roundly shaped medium is to burn it on DVD. It does not matter how big the image is. A DVD can hold data from 1MB to 4GB.

Comment: Hmmmm, well its labled DVD for 12.04.1 "ubuntu-12.04.1-dvd-i386.iso". When I tried to burn the 700Meg plus iso nero rejected the 700Meg CD as too small and the dvd as unsuitable also. I will have to try this again. Thanks.

Comment: ok, got both 12.10 iso and 12.04.1 iso burned onto DVD. Problem was changing the burning software Nero to DVD from CD. It might help others to put into the docs that the latest image can only fit onto USB Stick, DVD or special 800Meg CD in the case of 12.10. or maybe it does state that and I missed it. Thanks again everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the minimal cd iso which you can download from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD). It's only 34MB so it's able to fit on a CD.

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing Ubuntu **12.04** via CD and then upgrading it immediately after installation to 12.10.

To do that, check out [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-to-ubuntu-12-10) on OMG!Ubuntu!

Comment: Clean install is always recommended.

Comment: If they do not have access to a USB, and can only use a CD, this might be the only way for them to get 12.10. It's only a workaround for people constrained by difficult technical circumstances. I agree though that it is not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah,as david6 said, you can use a Flash USB device.uncompress the files in the iso to you USB device and boot from the USB device just like your CD.(you can use ultraISO to uncompress the iso to your usb device)

Answer (score 1):

Your two alternatives are either to burn a DVD or to make an Ubuntu live USB.

#### Burn a DVD

1. Insert a blank DVD into your burner. A *CD/DVD Creator*, *Choose Disc Type* or *Blank Disc* window might pop up. Close this, because you will not be using it.

   [image: IMG:]
   <sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>
2. 16.04 LTS no longer comes with a CD/DVD burner, so install Brasero Disc Burner. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install brasero
   ```
3. Open Brasero and click on the *Burn image* button.

   [image]
4. Select the ISO you downloaded in the *Select a disc image to writ*e box and your DVD drive in the *Select a disc to write to* box and click the *Burn* button.

   [image: IMG:]
   <sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>
5. Once the DVD is burned, you can restart your computer and try or install Ubuntu.

   [image: IMG:]
   <sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

#### Make an Ubuntu live USB

Instructions for how to make a bootable live Ubuntu USB from both Windows and Mac are in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191980/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick/317757#317757).

Answer (score 0):

One potential workaround, if you don't have a USB stick or a DVD burner, is to copy the image to a hard drive partition and boot from that (`dd if=ubuntu12.10.iso of=/dev/sda5`, for instance, if you have an unused partition at /dev/sda5). This limits your partitioning options during setup, of course.

If you use your swap partition for this, you might save yourself a bit of trouble, since swap is the easiest thing to deal with after install.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a USB, as other had stated. You can get one for pretty cheap from your local Staples or other such market.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I am going to try an answer anyway.

There are some `mini.iso` files that have been created that are anywhere from 27MB ~ 40MB in size.  After you have created the CD / USB media with one, it boots up and starts to download the required packages.  Recommended to do this with a hard wired connection (I don't think I was able to get it to connect wireless until after the installation).

After the required installation packages are downloaded, it then asks you all the packages you want installed.  It even has the ability to install the GNOME Desktop without Unity, and vice versa.

The files can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).

Hope this helps!