# Is there a way to create an installation CD instead of a DVD?

Tags: installation, dvd, cd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I burn the 790Meg ISO to a CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203601/how-do-i-burn-the-790meg-iso-to-a-cd)

Is there also a way to create an installation CD instead of a DVD for the latest version of Ubuntu 12.10 ?