# iso image too big for a cd

Tags: 12.10, burning, cd-image, file-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I burn the 12.10 790MB ISO to a CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203601/how-do-i-burn-the-12-10-790mb-iso-to-a-cd)

I downloaded the file for Ubuntu 12.10. It is a CD iso image with size of 753 MBytes. That exceeds the capacity of a CD-R disk, which is 700 MBytes. So what can be done to resolve this?

Is it intended that the downloaded file be converted to DVD image form and then burned on a writable DVD?