# Ubuntu Install - Won't fit on CD

Tags: installation, files, cd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I burn the 12.10 790MB ISO to a CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203601/how-do-i-burn-the-12-10-790mb-iso-to-a-cd)
>   [iso image too big for a cd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221584/iso-image-too-big-for-a-cd)

Ubuntu won't fit on a CD
I need to install to a clean drive and have downloaded Ubuntu 12.10.
The file size exceeds the CD capacity so I can't burn it to CD.
Target computer has CD. not DVD.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1: Use a liveUSB (recommended)

You may create it using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net) on Windows, Mac or Linux.

You must make sure the computer is able to boot from it and set it up accordingly either by going in the Bios settings and set up the USB before the hard disk in the boot priority list or pressing some key (F12 on some PCs) to pop up the boot menu on boot that permits choosing the boot medium.

## Option 2: Install Ubuntu 12.04.1, then upgrade.

If you have difficulties booting from USB, you may install Ubuntu 12.04.1, which fits on a CD and then upgrade your system.

## Option 3: Install Ubuntu 12.10 Server edition, then install the ubuntu-desktop package

Again, you could boot from an Ubuntu Server install CD, then in a terminal you could type `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and reboot (`sudo reboot`).

## Option 4: Install using the netboot version of the Ubuntu installer

This will download all the packages from the internet. It is recommended only if you have a fast internet connection.

Download the mini.iso from [this site](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/) and burn it to a CD.

Comment: Your link is broken (for the mini.iso) which I guess is because they do not support Ubuntu 12.x anymore. For 18.04, it is here: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ I think a better link would be to just http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ then you can explain where to go from there so people can use the latest version long term.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a DVD, a usb stick is your best option, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick