# Bootable Version of Ubuntu to burn onto a CD (NOT DVD)

Tags: cd-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I burn the 12.10 790MB ISO to a CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203601/how-do-i-burn-the-12-10-790mb-iso-to-a-cd)

Is there a *.ISO copy (old one even) of Ubuntu that I can burn onto a CD so I can install it and then upgrade to the latest version.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can download the 12.04 LTS version from the officeial site: http://ubuntu.com . I would not go for any older version, as there won't be a direct upgrade path to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts

This is a link to a 695MB install iso.

Comment: I know it sounds silly but my CDs only burn 650MB!!

Comment: @RPMGREEN - You might be able to fit it by enabling "overburn." Basically, what overburn does is allow more data to be written to the disk than the advertised size. Not all disks can do this, and your software will probably tell you that it might ruin the disk, but in my experience, I've never had issues (especially with small overburn amounts like yours), and worst case scenario, you're out a single CD-R.

Comment: @RPMGREEN: I know it sounds silly, but for the past decade or longer they could be burned up to (and slightly above) 700 MiB. Perhaps you should have mentioned this prerequisite of yours in the question, as it is pretty specific?!

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a USB stick and create a "Live USB" instead of a Live CD. All you need is one that's at least 768MB, which should be dirt cheap, and with the added bonus of being reusable.

Comment: Guys thanks for your help - it has probably been 10 years since I have burned a CD and that is what I have in the draw! I am burning version 5.10 and will upgrade from there. Wish me luck and thanks again.

Comment: Sounds perfect I'll try that.

Comment: Thanks I am up and running on the latest version. Cheers.

Comment: @WarrenHill I *highly* recommend posting an separate answer about that (as that appears to be the solution).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternate Image. This however is a text based installer. It is still pretty simple to install however you can not try the OS out first.

[Ubuntu Releases Archive](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: I am not sure that is true. I used the Alternate CD just the other day.


Alternate CD - Ubuntu 12.04 amd64: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso


Alternate CD - Ubuntu 12.04 i386
http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-i386.iso

Comment: Sorry, I ought to have been more specific. Starting with Ubuntu 12.10, there is no alternate CD. Just the desktop DVD and server CD--see [the file list](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/). And, as before, the [minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).

Comment: Okay, I just figured it would be easier for you to have moved up from 12.04 than from 5.10. But as long as it worked it doesn't really matter, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here 
http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

It's a command line install and needs working internet (preferably Wired) to install.