# Replacing Windows Vista with Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.02

Tags: system-installation

I'm a Ubuntu "newbie", and am just starting to learn Linux (thanks to Eli the Computer Guy).  I am an IBM System i Administrator; but have extensive PC experience in the Windows world; but, very little Linux knowledge at this point.  I have an eMachines Model ET6141-D2W Desktop that had Windows Vista (2.00 Ghz Processor, 2GB RAM, 288GB HD.  The boot sector became corrupted; so, it no longer boots into Windows; but, I can place it into a SATA docking station, and still access all the data; i.e., my pics, docs, etc., which I have backed up to DVDs.  I want to install Ubuntu 12.04.02 Desktop on it; but when I try to boot from the DVD I burned from the ubuntu-12.04.02-desktop-i386.iso, it just keeps recycling; i.e., goes through the motions, but never boots from the DVD, even though I changed the boot order to boot from DVD drive first.  What am I doing wrong?  I just downloaded InfraRecorder, and am downloading the iso again, and will use InfraRecorder to burn to DVD.  I'm thinking the iso didn't burn properly when I first tried using Windows Vista Burn program.

On another note: The ubuntu-12.04.02-desktop-i386.iso says it's 693MB; but when I tried to burn it to a CD-RW 700MB disk, it said it required 727MB available.  I have a couple of other older PCs I'd like to play around with installing ubuntu on; but, they only have CD-ROM drives, not DVDs.  How can I get the 12.04.02-desktop iso to fit on a CD, or is that not possible?

Thanx in advance for the help.

Comment: You could put Ubuntu on an USB to boot on older computers, so long as they support Boot to USB. If not, you can switch DVD drives from computer, just for the install.

Comment: What's the graphics chip/card? (for **eMachines ET6141**) *I can only find a **Gateway (eMachines)**, series **ET**, model **1641**!?* Is this it: http://www.ascendtech.us/emachines-et1641-02w-dual-core-e1400-pc_i_pcemacet164102w.aspx

Comment: david6:  Yes, that is it.  BTW:  I'm not having much success with the Boot to USB route.  I don't think this eMachines recognizes USB drives as "bootable" drives.  I followed the online instructions; i.e., downloaded and installed ISO to USB Installer (Ver 1 - Freeware); and created a "bootable" USB drive withe Ubuntu 12.04.02-desktop-i386.iso, and even though I've gone into CMOS and Setup on my eMachines to make sure it points to the "Generic Flash Drive" as my boot source; it will not boot from it.  It keeps bypassing it and goes straight into Windows.  Gettin' kinda frustrated.  :O(

Comment: Making some progress.  Started from "square one", downloaded Ubuntu V12.04.02-desktop-i386.iso; used InfraRecorder to image a CD-RW; that kept erroring out (I think because of the 700MB limit); so, I gave up and burned it to a DVD, and was finally able to boot to it on my eMachines ET6141 Desktop.  Selected option to Try Ubuntu, and the desktop loaded ok; but immediately received driver error for Broadcom 802.11 driver not activated.  I selected Activate, and I got a bunch of machine code on the screen; then it just sat there forever.  I pressed the return key, and the screen colors went crazy

Comment: Will have to check other posts here to see if others have had similar issues.  It wouldn't recognize my wireless network (probably because of the missing/compatible drivers).  I think my next step will be to install it on my other eMachine that has the boot sector issue; i.e., just do an install of Ubuntu on it and wipe the old WinVista drive.  More too come; but I'm encouraged, now.

Comment: BTW:  My other "older" PCs don't support booting from flash drive, and don't have DVD drives (only CD-ROM drives); so, probably won't be able to install Ubuntu on them at all.

Answer (score 0):

Some older machines do not 'honor' the boot order settings.

Keep trying, and try the 'manual boot' method of choosing the boot device. *This usually resolves the problem.*

---

I strongly suggest using a 2GB USB device as the install media.

See: [How do I burn the Ubuntu ISO to a CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203601/how-do-i-burn-the-12-10-790mb-iso-to-a-cd)

*Basically, when **12.10** was released, it no longer would fit on a CD (without some non-standard compression / format workaround). And, **12.04.2** in newer still.*

**Note:** *On my PC the **ubuntu-12.04.02-desktop-i386.iso** file is **727.0 MB**. It may be the platform / file structure you have it stored on, or it could be corrupt.*

Comment: Thanx for the feedback, Max and David6.  The eMachines PC is useless to me unless I reformat the drive with some flavor of Windows; so, I figured it would be a good candidate for ubuntu; but, from what you're saying, maybe not.  I have a couple of other older PCs; e.g., a Dell GX150 with CD-ROM and USB, that may work, and an older Compaq Presario 5210 that has a CD-ROM drive and an Iomega Zip drive.  I may give one of those a shot.  David6:  I'll try using a USB device and see how that goes.  I'll let you know the results.  Thanx, again, both of you.

Comment: I am blown away!  I just installed Ubuntu-12.04.02-desktop on my eMachines PC that had an issue with the boot sector; i.e., it wouldn't boot into Windows Vista.  I chose to do the "side-by-side" install.  The install took about an hour from DVD; but it was well worth the wait; because to my very delighted surprise ALL of my documents, pics, videos, music, etc. are still there and accessible.  I just double click on the OS icon, and I see my Windows Vista environment, and can navigate to Documents and Settings, all the Users are still there, and all their docs, pics, music, etc.  I am amazed!

Comment: With a ***bbot sector*** issue, backup ALL your old data (now that you have access). Then check the quality and likely work life of this drive. *You may want to replace the drive ..*

Comment: David: I was able to backup all my old data to DVDs before I discovered Ubuntu; so, I could've just installed Ubuntu Desktop wiping away the old Windows Vista environment; but, since I'm new to Ubuntu, I chose to do a "side-by-side" install initially.  I'm going to play around with it for a few weeks, and, when I'm ready to dive into Ubuntu exclusively; I'll just reinstall it, and use the entire drive space exclusively for Ubuntu.  Right now, the "dual-boot" environment is desirable; even though I can't really "boot" into Windows Vista, at least I can get to my data. I've got a lot to learn.