# Convert a live CD to a bootable USB

Tags: installation, 13.04, live-usb, live-cd

I bought an Ubuntu CD that contains an [ISO image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) file (.iso). I want to install Ubuntu on a netbook and it cannot be done by the CD, so I have to install Ubuntu by USB.
How can I convert the Ubuntu CD to a bootable USB?

Comment: Hey! Live CD is nothing but the boot-able CD!! :P You were not able to boot from CD because you might not have changed the `first boot priority to CD/DVD Drive` from bios.. Check it once..

Comment: @SauravKumar he uses net book which mostly wont have cd drive .He wants a usb installation

Comment: @Stormvirux Oh!! My Mistake.. How many `books` has come.. :D Then possibly he has to use some other system to copy image and has to use `startup disk creator` to create USB Bootable.

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick or http://askubuntu.com/questions/203601/how-do-i-burn-the-790mb-iso-to-a-cd

Comment: @Braiam Those questions don't seem to ask (or have answers) about creating USB installation media *starting with a CD rather than an ISO image.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**From Ubuntu**

[USB installation Guide from Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Creating_a_bootable_Ubuntu_USB_flash_drive)

There's a package called usb-creator-gtk (and usb-creator-kde for KDE-desktop).
It can be found in the Unity Dash
This application has a GUI to copy an iso/or from cd to a USB-drive and make it bootable.

**From Windows**

You can use the software [LinuxLive](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) to create a Bootable USB in Windows.

[image]