# Partition resize after ubuntu on windows8

Tags: partitioning, resize

I have got a weird problem and I ended up getting 3 partitions after installing ubuntu on windows 8.

In sequence:
1. windows 8 - main partition
2. Grub - 1 MB
3. ubuntu - 38 GB + Swap (5 GB)
4. 20 GB partition which I had partitioned before installing ubuntu thinking that I will install ubuntu on this partition

(The ubuntu 13.04 got installed on original C:\ drive itself and took out 38.12 GB.)

Here is my prob:
I want to move 20 GB partition to C drive and make total size of ubuntu as 20 GB instead of current 38 GB.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed ubuntu via wubi. Please remove that and try installing at system bootup process. To do that Follow steps mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191980/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick).

And while installing you could choose `do something else` option to select the partition and swap area.I don't remember the correct options which the installer will show but they will be:

1. install side by side
2. remove windows and install
3. do something else.

Note: Please be sure the partition you select is the partition you want ubuntu to install. Selecting incorrect partition may wipe out the windows also.

Comment: I havent't installed using wubi. Wubi isnt supported on windows 8. I installed side by side only but it took space from windows 8 partition

Comment: then you can remove the reference for the already installed Ubuntu by using [msconfig](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/using-system-configuration) and then delete the Ubuntu Filesystem in your windows partition. then you can follow my steps.

Comment: Okey.. Will try that out but only thing is it should boot up (i.e. grub shouldnt get messed up or something)