# Installation problems through Ubuntu bootable CD

Tags: system-installation, live-cd

I used InfraRecorder to burn Ubuntu on a CD and boot my computer, and I also managed to get the Ubuntu logo to pop up after booting from the CD I made.

I did the manual installation, but at the end it says `mirror bad archive mirror`.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the `mirror bad archive mirror` error message because you burnt the Ubuntu ISO to a CD and the current Ubuntu ISOs are too big to fit on a CD. There was a time when the Ubuntu 12.04 ISO could be burnt to a CD, but it has been updated, and now the Ubuntu 12.04.3 ISO is too big to fit on a CD, and so are the ISOs for later Ubuntu releases. So now your two alternatives are to burn the Ubuntu ISO to a DVD or else make an Ubuntu live USB and boot Ubuntu from that.

For more information about how to make an Ubuntu live USB see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191980/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick/317757#317757).