# First time using Ubuntu, a few questions

Tags: usb, dell, system-installation, android

So my gf's dell inspiron 1545 has had a pirated copy of windows 7 ultimate since we got it (from her mom and we think her step dad put the pirated copy on it)
She's sick of having an illegal copy and lately it has been pretty glitchy.
We'd like to put ubuntu on it instead. I don't have any blank dvds, or a usb drive, but I have my android with a 16gb sd card. Is it possible to boot from the android's sd card instead of a usb drive?
If not, would it be better to us a usb or burn it to a dvd?
Let me know if I missed any important info!

Comment: A [USB flash drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/191980/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick/317757#317757), 2GB or larger, would be better than a DVD, faster and more likely to boot properly than an SD card.

Comment: Thanks! I just went out and picked up a 16gb sandisk cruzer.
So I'm copying ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso to it now, then I just plug it in to her computer and restart it right? Making sure I go into the boot menu and tell it to boot from usb? Or am I missing a step? 

Edit - Actually I'm checking out  
http://askubuntu.com/questions/191980/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick?lq=1  
and  
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows  
now

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a BIOS that can boot from an SD card, but if it's present in your boot options menu (varies per system), then go for it! Just burn the ISO using tools like [Universal USB Installer.](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

If, however, your BIOS doesn't, then you'd have to find a USB reader for your microSD to burn the ISO and boot from it.