# Installing Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: boot, windows-8

After rebooting and choose to boot from DVD that contain Ubuntu ISO. Then the ubuntu logo appear and when total black and nothing happen. Is there any solution for this problem? I wanted to make dual boot and currently using windows 8.1.

Comment: Welcome on this Site! Please add a little system information. wich pc? 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to boot from a different boot disk? You can download [ubuntu iso for free](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso) then extract it using winrar and put it on a usb then boot onto the usb and the you can install!

Answer (score 0):

Is it a rewritable DVD? If yes - erase and format it fully. Now burn again the image of Ubuntu at ***slow*** write speed. And first of all check the integrity of the ISO image (just to make sure that the image is not damaged/incomplete). Must work if everything is okay. Another option is creating a bootable USB of Ubuntu. Just follow these instructions to do so - [Creating Ubuntu bootable USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191980/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick).

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in windows 8 PCs called Secure boot.
This stops you from doing anything to you current hard disk configuration. You have to disable this feature form BIOS and also set the BIOS mode to Compatability or UEFI and Legacy OS. This should do the trick