# Persistent live USB Ubuntu 14 not working

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, live-usb, persistence

Used [Fedora Live USB creator](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/) 3.12 to create a live USB of Ubuntu 14 (latest 64 bit build)

I can successfully boot the USB on my Surface Pro 3 but I cannot get the persistence to work.
It is not an option in the Grub menu either.  I am using a 32GB drive and I did enable a 4gb partition for persistence.

Comment: [UNetbootin](http://askubuntu.com/questions/191980/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick/317757#317757) is a native Ubuntu app and it is also in the Fedora repos.

Comment: as said by @karel unetbootin gives you option for persistent data storage on live USB

Comment: Unetbootin may be better, it might work. Try that!

Comment: Could we please stop recommending UNetbootin for UEFI and Windows 8 machines? I have nothing personal against the tool itself, there have just been too many users booting their new machines in legacy mode and wrecking their existing installations.

Comment: I tried UNetbootin with the same results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB Live Pen Persistent Boot disk- in UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025847/usb-live-pen-persistent-boot-disk-in-uefi)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like bug [LP #1159016](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1159016).  Persistence not working on UEFI machines.  You can fix this problem by editing the `/EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg` file and adding the word `persistent` to the lines starting with `linux`.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, given that the Fedora Live USB creator doesn't do modifications to the layout, which I'm not sure of. For UEFI the easiest way would be to just copy the files contained in the ISO to USB, then modifying said `grub.cfg` to add persistence should work http://askubuntu.com/q/395879/40581

Comment: I don't see /EFI/ubuntu at all.  Just /EFI/BOOT

Comment: I used `unetbootin`, but had the same issue in Wily.  On a live Wily USB, the file is in `/cdrom/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.  It was mounted readonly, so I had to remount before I edited, using `mount -o rw,remount /cdrom`.