# Booting UBUNTU please help!

Tags: system-installation

As I'm going to download a 64 bit Ubuntu version and save it to my pen-drive, but the problem is as I copy that setup to my pen-drive,,, How is it going to boot on startup, It cannot boot automatically,,, Can anyone please help me regarding this????

Answer (score 0):

You have to get either into your BIOS/UEFI's boot menu and select your USB drive to boot from (recommended, as it is a just-once setting) or enter your BIOS/UEFI-Setup and change your boot order there so that USB is listed before HDD (not recommended, as it is a permanent setting and you could harm your PC if you change other options without knowing what you're doing).

But of course, therefore you must have a bootable USB device! Just copying the ISO or some files to the volume is not enough. Look this up here [How to create a bootable USB stick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191980/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick)