# How do I reformat a USB flash drive after burning Ubuntu Server onto it?

Tags: system-installation, usb, windows, windows-10, iso

I have downloaded the Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 LTS ISO, then I burned the ISO to a USB flash drive.

Then, I attempted to verify the burnt ISO, however the application said that the USB may be corrupted.

I tried reformatting the USB with a Windows® application, however this failed, notifying me that the USB device may be faulty. I then tried booting from the USB flash drive, and was successful.

These two USB flash drives are relatively new, obtained in January.

Is it the software I used? Can I somehow recover the USB?

Comment: Your USB *should* be fine. It has probably modified the partitioning table. You may not be able to create partitions alongside this, however you can reformat the USB afterwards.

Comment: Minimum life for a flash drive is 10000 writes, this is quite a while if the drive is 64GB.

Comment: @luk3yx i have formated them using windows but it has not worked should i use a partitioning program to repartition it  ???

Comment: @thanatos7930 I'd use a Linux utility like gparted myself. Don't just format it, try and create a new partition table as well.

Comment: @luk3yx you were right i downloaded aomei partition assistant and it did change the partition table i created a new partition table and it works perfectly thanx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a bootable USB stick?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/191980/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a USB flash drive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22381/how-to-format-a-usb-flash-drive)

Answer (score 1):

so it turns out that when i burned the iso image to the usb it modified the partition table and all i had to do was repartition the whole flash drive and it works perfectly (i used AOMEI partition assistant to partition the flash drive found here :http://www.disk-partition.com/ on windows 10)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: The program you mentioned doesn't appear to be available for Linux.  **GParted** as suggested by luk3yx would do the job in this environment.  It's available in the LiveUSB as well as via the Ubuntu repository.  Suggesting Windows tools for Ubuntu users, especially for some of the noobs can be confusing.

Comment: im sorry that  i didnt give a good answer i am a noob when it comes to linux ubuntu and i know next to nothing about servers GParted would work fine i can try explain in my answer how to do it with GParted if that works i have used it before i do want you to know  i have a lot of trouble communicating almost everything if you would like and are willing  i could dm/pm one of you @DavidFoerster or L. D. James  about what i did to fix the prob and you could edit it i know thats asking a lot what do you recomend i do

Comment: There are no private messages on StackExchange. However you can just [edit] your own answer and ask someone to have a look at it if you think they may improve it.