# How do I solve Error 13: Invalid or unsupported executable format when trying to install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, unetbootin

I'm trying my hand at getting my laptop to run Ubuntu.

My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite L755-S5153. It came preloaded with Windows 7. I upgraded the laptop to Windows 10.

I downloaded the Ubuntu 16.04.3 disk image (ISO) file to the laptop's hard drive.

UNetbootin was downloaded and run. The type was set to hard disk and Diskimage was set to where the ISO file was downloaded. I pressed OK, and UNetbootin proceeded without any problem.

When I try to boot from UNetbootin, I get a black screen with the this error:

```
Booting 'UNetbootin'

 (hd0,1)
 Filesystem type is ntfs, partitiom type 0x7
kernel  /unetbtin/ubnkern 
Error 13: Invalid or unsupported executable format

Press any key to continue..._
```

Answer (score 1):

The bootloader that is supposed to load the Ubuntu live USB that was created with UNetbootin is not loading correctly. I recommend scrapping the UNetbootin Ubuntu live USB and trying again with the Ubuntu USB creator application for your operating system that is recommended [at the official Ubuntu website](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows?backURL=%2F#0). See this question: [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso).

If you are making the Ubuntu live USB on windows with Rufus, which is the recommended application, there are detailed step-by-step instructions accompanied by several screenshots at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191980/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick/317757#317757).

Comment: Thanks Karel. I tried the USB approach using Rufus. Unfortunately, I ran into the problem, Failed to load ldlinux.c32 Boot failed: please change disk and press a key to continue. I'm not sure how to continue

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. Your Toshiba Satellite laptop isn't loading the Ubuntu live USBs that were made with either UNetbootin or Rufus, so you need to give it a smaller .iso that will load faster. The Ubuntu minimal CD is only 60MB. See the accepted answer to this question: [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd). Alternatively you could try it again using a different USB flash drive.

Comment: Noted Karel. I'm trying to download the mini versions but am having connection problems. I'll try to download later and will give an update. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Good morning -

i simply had to do following steps to get my usb-stick booting:

- copy /backup all important files already placed upon usb stick (just in case)
- gparted: device (=usb), new partition table, msdos,
- then in windows (10/etc/rescue dvd) with usb stick plugged in:
  diskpart, list disk, select disk 1 (=> or 2 or 3, aka your usb stick according to SIZE of disk), attributes disk clear readonly (clears readonly feature), online disk, convert mbr (= fixes partition structure)
  (- format to fat32 or  fat (if below 1GB)  or exfat)
- use unetbootin / rufus / ventoy again and try booting, please..

install linux :-)