# Can I run Windows virtually in Ubuntu for testing? What about Windows only software and drivers?

Tags: drivers, windows, virtualization

I am a developer and I really want to switch to Ubuntu. When I switch to Ubuntu, can I run Windows virtually (VirtualBox) for some testing?

I often use photo editing software like Photoshop; can I run it on Ubuntu?

I have a lot of questions about the drivers. Can I support USB 3.0, audio, touchpad, video drivers smoothly like running on Windows (mainly I need my touchpad drivers for some shortcuts and drivers?

Comment: Try running a live USB session, that will tell you if your drivers work or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I run Windows virtually (VirtualBox)?

Yes, you can if your hardware supports it. Modern x86(-64) PCs do support it.

> I often use some photo editing software like Photoshop can I run it on Ubuntu?

You cannot run Photoshop directly on Ubuntu but you can try free alternatives like [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) or get Photoshop working in VirtualBox or [in Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?iId=17&sClass=application).

> And I have a lot of questions about the drivers.

You can (and should!) try Ubuntu before installing. Get your install medium, boot it and select **Try Ubuntu without installing**. It will boot a live session without any changes to your hard drive, so you can check all your requirements and ask a specific question here if you encounter any problems.

See also:

- [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)
- [How to create a bootable USB stick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191980/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick)
- [Try Ubuntu before you install it](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)

Comment: can i try installing drivers. mainly i need my touch pad drivers dell touchpad

Comment: @Musthu Yes, you can try to install them in the live session. Of course, after you install Ubuntu on your hard drive, you’ll have to install them again.

Comment: but i have some issues on audio playback

Comment: i installed the codec and music can be played from the video player but the default player didn't support that

Comment: @Musthu Please [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) about that and provide as many details as you can (the Ubuntu version, your hardware specification, what codec you installed and how etc.).